# Access all properties of an unknown type

Tags: c#, .net

On my WinForm,  I want to show each Property (as a label) and its value at run time depending on the type of the object. Something like this:

```
public void ShowDetails(object anyType)
{
// Generate label per property and show value of the property against a label.
}
```

How can I achieve this? There are more than 100 classes having different properties.

I am using C# 4.0.

Comment: One word, Reflection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use reflection.

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    object propertyValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

That should be enough to get you started.

You can also get lots of other information out of the `PropertyInfo` such as the name of the property, the type, the accessibility, and so on.  Note that it's possible (but very uncommon) to have a property without a getter, so you may want to check for that first.  You also may want to only get *public* properties, rather than *all* properties.  You also may want to check if the property is an indexer, as it will need a non-null value for the second parameter of `GetValue`.  Oh, and you will also get static properties returned; you may or may not want those as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo` . You can loop through all properties (and sub-properties)

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily store the properties and their values in a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string,object> properties = anyType.GetType()
                              .GetProperties()
                              .ToDictionary(p=>p.Name,p=>p.GetValue(anyType,null));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd read up on [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It will allow you to access the property names and values of class member at runtime.